# Akka FSM Actor with stashing and unstashing

Tags: scala, akka, akka-fsm

I would like to do stashing/unstashing with FSM Akka Acctor. I don't know where to put the `stash()` and `unstashAll()`.

I have a simplified example below:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, FSM, Props, Stash}

trait TestState
case object StateA extends TestState
case object StateB extends TestState

case class TestData()

case class MessageA(msg: String)
case class MessageB(msg: String)
case object ChangeState

class TestFSM extends FSM[TestState, TestData] with Stash {

  startWith(StateA, TestData())

  when(StateA) {
    case Event(MessageA(msgA), _) =>
      println(s"In StateA: $msgA")
      stay()
    case Event(ChangeState, _) =>
      println("Changing state from A to B")
      goto(StateB)
  }

  when(StateB) {
    case Event(MessageB(msgB), _) =>
      println(s"In StateB: $msgB")
      stay()
  }

  whenUnhandled {
    case Event(e, _) =>
      println(s"Unhandled event: $e")
      stay()
  }
}

object TestFSM extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("test-system")
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[TestFSM])

  actor ! MessageA("Apple 1")
  actor ! MessageB("Banana 1")
  actor ! MessageA("Apple 2")

  actor ! ChangeState

  actor ! MessageB("Banana 2")
}
```

The initial state is `StateA`. 
When in `StateA` the actor should only handle messages of type `MessageA`. If it receives any other type of message (except for `ChangeState`) it should stash it. Upon receiving a message `ChangeState`, the actor should change to `StateB`. 
Upon changing from `StateA` to `StateB`, it should unstash all the messages.
When in `StateB` the actor should only handle messages of type `MessageB`.

I am not sure exactly where to use the `stash()` and `unstashAll()` to achieve this.

The output that I get on running is:

```
In StateA: Apple 1
Unhandled event: MessageB(Banana 1)
In StateA: Apple 2
Changing state from A to B
In StateB: Banana 2
```

The output I would like to see is:

```
In StateA: Apple 1
In StateA: Apple 2
Changing state from A to B
In StateB: Banana 1
In StateB: Banana 2
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `onTransition` method on the `FSM`. This gets executed when a state change occurs and we can use that moment to unstash all messages. As for stashing, you need to do it in the `whenUnhandled` method. I've also made a small update so you can cycle between states:

```scala
class TestFSM extends FSM[TestState, TestData] with Stash {
  startWith(StateA, TestData())

  when(StateA) {
    case Event(MessageA(msgA), _) =>
      println(s"In StateA: $msgA")
      stay()
    case Event(ChangeState, _) =>
      println("Changing state from A to B")
      goto(StateB)
  }

  when(StateB) {
    case Event(MessageB(msgB), _) =>
      println(s"In StateB: $msgB")
      stay()
    case Event(ChangeState, _) =>
      println("Changing state from B to A")
      goto(StateA)
  }

  /**
    * Here we can stash all messages. For example when we're in state A,
    * we handle both `MessageA` and `ChangeState` messages, but we don't
    * handle `MessageB` instances which will end up here. The opposite
    * happens when we're in state B.
    */
  whenUnhandled {
    case _: Event =>
      stash()
      stay()
  }

  // When transitioning into another state, unstash all messages.
  onTransition {
    case StateA -> StateB => unstashAll()
    case StateB -> StateA => unstashAll()
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any more questions :)

Comment: I'm glad tot hear that :)